# Increment ID on insertion of a new row on database

Tags: java, sql, triggers, insert, increment

I need something which I dont know if it's possible to achieve. Basically I'll be adding new rows of information from java to a database with the table structure , ex:

```
Number | Color | Size

   0   |  Red  | Big

   1   | Green | Small

   2   | Yellow| Medium
```

I'm using java and I'll only input the Color and Size,  and I would like to know if it's possible to create a trigger that will store the variable Number(id) on the database side, and increment it each time I do an Insert of a new row into the db. I was thinking doing something like, " INSERT INTO table ((null),'Red', 'Big'), and then the database would update the value with the proper Number.
Also should be possible to bare with fact that some rows can be deleted, but it won'shouldn't affect anything, example: if I have ID's 0 , 1 ,2 and I delete 1, next row should still be 3.

Another thing, I'm using Sybase SQL Anywhere 12 to do this.

Comment: Look up `identity` columns for Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

You should use autoincrement column in your database.

See this.

http://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa/autoincrement_identity

Answer (score 1):

As @Gordon Linoff said ...

Identity columns are doing that, for example ...

```
create table T1 (ID int identity(1,1), Name nvarchar(100))
```

In this case you would go ...

```
insert into T1 (Name) values ('John')
```

So, you would insert Name 'John' and DB itself would give him ID 1
Next time you do insert, ID 2 would be set ... and so on and on ..

```
Identity(1,1) - it means start from 1 and increment it by 1 on new insert
```

Thing about this is that once number is taken, there is no going back, so if you have IDs 1, 2, 3 .. and delete ID 3 .. on next insert ID will go up to 4, it will not populate "missing number"

Comment: Thank you for your input, though I'd like to ask how would I proceed if I had one more column, for example, the ID, Name and Age?
More specifically, the Insert query, I coudln't figure it out

**EDIT**: just figured it out after all hehe.. would be something like:
insert into T1 (Name,Age) values ('John','20')

Comment: Good job man! columns that are identity, you never put in insert statement as they are self incremented. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

there are several solutions that satisfy your requirements but those are different in several aspects and you should decide to select the best one.

some solutions are exists in DB context. (for example @Gregory answer), 
but some other solutions are independent of the DB type and specific features. it means that you implement your solution independent of your db type and you could change your db (oracle, sql-server, my-sql , ...) and there is no need to change your java code. 
in jpa there are three Sequence Strategies to solving this problem with @GeneratedValue.

1) Table sequencing: you use a separate table for this purpose in your db. this table hold the proper ids for other tables that have auto-increment-columns with this strategy.

2) Sequence objects: you use a sequence object in your db and jpa handle it. Sequence objects are only supported in some databases, such as Oracle, DB2, and Postgres.

3) Identity sequencing: uses special IDENTITY columns in the database to allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases, such as MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, and PostgreSQL. Oracle does not support IDENTITY columns but it is possible to simulate them using sequence objects and triggers.

**if you want to be independent from your db type, I recommend you to use "table strategy" in jpa.**

see [Java Persistence/Identity and Sequencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing) for details.

you asked:

> I would like to know if it's possible to create a trigger that will
>   store the variable Number(id) on the database side, and increment it
>   each time I do an Insert of a new row into the db.

yes, you could use trigger, but as i mentioned there are some simpler solutions rather it.

> Also should be possible to bare with fact that some rows can be
>   deleted, but it won'shouldn't affect anything

in jpa solutions the deleted ids don't be used in next usage, but if you implement your own solution you could use them.

I hope this answer help you.